# Rails stylesheets placed in assets don't show on website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet, asset-pipeline

I have a set of custom stylesheets in **assets/stylesheets/xxx** folder.

I have a custom **application_xxx.css.scss** file in **assets/** that requires all of those.

I have a custom layout **xxx_application.html.haml** which includes:

```
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application_xxx'
```

Everything works nicely in development, when I push everything now to the testing server none of the stylesheets are working. it gives a msg "Failed to load resource **application_xxx.css** "

Do I have to place my custom folder and custom application file in the public directory instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you precompiled assets?

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

You don't need to manually move any any custom css or js.  Precompile your assets then try pushing again.

My production.rb file has these relevant lines:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( application-all.css application-print.css )
config.assets.compile = false
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Comment: Thanks! I just did and nothing happened but I think there is a missing step too because we're using capistrano. I'll ask the team on Monday Morning and update this.

Comment: I added this line to my staging.rb config.assets.precompile += [%w(application_xxx.css)] but it didn't do anything ... I still don't see my stylesheet in /public/